# The mysql-bin.xxxx files are growing very fast

Tags: mysql

I have a replication enviroment and is working fine, but today my disk going full.

I check and see that the `mysql-bin.xxx` files are growing very very fast (I know they contain all changes in the database(s), so naturally they will grow, but today it is not normal the way that they are growing... that is, very fast and continuously!).

Then I use `mysqlbinlog` to see the content of de last `mysql-bin.xxx` file but is to dificult to see any error.

**My question**

Is there some way to perceive, check, anything... where or why my `mysql-bin` files are growing?

Comment: Do you have any big update to your DB? For example update x set y=1 where id < 1000000

Comment: No i do not have ... that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your application updated very large records. In this situation MySQL bin log growing fast.

But if you want to print row events from MySQL Bin Log, you Can use --verbose switch.

For example: I want to dump print row events from binlog.005594 to see statement.

```
mysqlbinlog --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS --verbose binlog.005594 > statement_dump
```

The output is like this:

```
UPDATE `users`.`posts`
WHERE
@1=4266310158
@2=9618518585
@3=54576
@4=NULL
@5=NULL
@6=NULL
@7=''
@8=2017-06-22 12:28:27
@9=1
@10=1827
@11=5933727040501033372
### SET
@1=4266310158
@2=9618518585
@3=54576
@4=NULL
@5=NULL
@6=NULL
@7=''
@8=2017-06-22 12:28:27
 @9=1
@10=1828
@11=5933727040501033372
```

@n are order of columns

---

Another tool for do this:

https://github.com/danfengcao/binlog2sql

I didn't test it

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, very grateful, I'll prove it

Comment: @ArnaldoRaxach you're welcome. If my post helped you please score my post. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Are you using replication?  If not, do you have the binlogs turned on for backups?

Do you have `expire_logs_days` set?  To what?

Give us some clues of what write queries are going on.

Are you `UPDATEing` all the rows in large tables?  If so, this is a sign of a mis-designed schema.

Are you doing massive `DELETEs`?  Let's discuss alternatives.

Comment: Yes, I am using replication and my expire_logs_days is in 2, obviously they should be making big modifications, apparently in the applications that consume the databases of the server, the behavior has calmed, that is to say it has not happened more, it must have been some Script of the side of the applications that towards mofificaciones, I suppose, when I have more time I dedicate myself to review more carefully. Thank you very much for your answers